# how to use pandas to organize sales data into 12 months and find the 10 most profitable products for those 12 months?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need write a program that organizes the data in the provided spreadsheet to find the top 10 most profitable products by each month. The program needs to take an input from the user to specify the year in which to compile the data. 
I've gotten as far as printing all of the products sold in each month by their highest profitability but I don't know how to make it print only the top 10 for each month. 
I'm also lost on how to take an input from the user to select only certain year for the program to compile the data.

Please help.

the link to download the files for my project: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VkzTWydV7Qae7hOn6WUjDQutQGmhRaDH?usp=sharing

```
import pandas as pd    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import seaborn as sns    

xl = pd.ExcelFile("SalesDataFull.xlsx")    
OrdersOnlyData = xl.parse("Orders")    

df_year = OrdersOnlyData["Order Date"].dt.year
OrdersOnlyData["Year"] = df_year

df_month = OrdersOnlyData["Order Date"].dt.month   

OrdersOnlyData["Month"] = df_month    
dataframe = OrdersOnlyData[["Year","Month","Product Name","Profit"]]

month_profit = dataframe.groupby(["Year","Month","Product Name"]).Profit.sum().sort_values(ascending=False)    
month_profit = month_profit.reset_index()

month_profit = month_profit.sort_values(["Year","Month","Profit"],ascending=[True,True,False])

print(month_profit)
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

As @Franco pointed out, it is difficult to recommend a proper solution since you did not provide a data sample together with your question. In any case, the function that you are looking for is most likely `nth()`.

This is probably how it should look like:

```
month_profit = month_profit.sort_values('Profit', ascending=False).groupby(['Year', 'Month']).nth([range(10)]).sort_values(by=['Year', 'Month', 'Profit'], ascending=[True, True, False])
```